# jquery isotope resize to handle expanded accordion

Tags: jquery, accordion

I'm using jquery isotope for a sortable text listing of federal regulatory activities. We list each update in a docket and the list per docket can become quite long. I've added Bootstrap simple accordion panels to items with more than two updates to make each item panel's height fairly consistent. When I open an accordion panel, the isotope pane doesn't resize to accommodate the expanded accordion.

Any ideas on how to get the isotope panel to resize height to handle the expanded accordions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To fix it, you need to initialize or layout after all the items have their proper size.
Just add this code:

```
$('.panel').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    $grid.isotope('layout');
})
```

Comment: smooth as silk :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in isotope for the simple lists layouts.

javascirpt:

```
$('.container').isotope({layoutMode: 'straightDown'})
```

after add a fix to your css to overwrite dynamic inline styles from the plugin execution:

```
.isotope .isotope-item {
    min-height: 0px !important;
    position: static !important;
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) !important;
}
.isotope-hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a function for the isotope "reLayout" in a callback.

```
function() {$('#container').isotope('reLayout');}
```

An example of where to put it:

```
$(this).next().slideDown(
    function() {$container.isotope('reLayout');}
);
```